# MySQL Stored procedure says alias is undefined in select statement

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, alias

I have the following statement, which produces this error. Apparently the alias "R" in the first line of the select statement is not declared, but it's right there at the end of the statement. Anyone have any ideas?

**#1327 - Undeclared variable: R**

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE `get_series_completion`(IN team1_id INT, IN team2_id INT, IN round_shortname VARCHAR(5))
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_games_total, num_games_played INT;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO num_games_played, R.games_per_series INTO num_games_total
    FROM (
        SELECT game_id
        FROM team_games
        WHERE team_id IN (team1_id, team2_id)
        GROUP BY game_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
            AND SUM(standing = 0) = 0
    ) AS S, rounds AS R ON R.round_shortname = round_shortname;

    SELECT num_games_played/num_games_total;
END$$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should select all columns before into clause, Your query should be:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), R.games_per_series INTO num_games_played, num_games_total
    FROM (
        SELECT game_id
        FROM team_games
        WHERE team_id IN (team1_id, team2_id)
        GROUP BY game_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
            AND SUM(standing = 0) = 0
    ) AS S 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN rounds AS R ON R.round_shortname = round_shortname;
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*), R.games_per_series INTO num_games_played, num_games_total
    FROM (
        SELECT game_id
        FROM team_games
        WHERE team_id IN (team1_id, team2_id)
        GROUP BY game_id
            HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
            AND SUM(standing = 0) = 0
    ) AS S, rounds AS R 
    WHERE R.round_shortname(+) = round_shortname; -- implicit left outer join
```

Comment: Oh, I'll try this. I switched the "LEFT JOIN" to "," and forgot to change that.

Comment: Still getting the same undeclared error with all variations of what you posted.

Comment: Doesn't seem to like the `(+)`? `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') = round_shortname;
        SELECT num_games_played/num_games_total;
    END' at line 14`